# объяснить мне за ООП ;-)

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

[image: код1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Недавно начал учить ООП на с++ и сразу же появился вопрос. Почему когда в 38 строке я записываю в переменную b значения таким образом, то ни конструктор, ни перегруженный оператор "="  не вызываются. Объясните пошагово, пожалуйста, как работает код в строке 38. Буду благодарен :) Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Point{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Point(){
        cout << "constructor1\t"<< this<<endl;
        x = NULL;
        y = NULL;
    };
    Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        cout << "constructor2\t"<< this <<endl;
    };
    ~Point()
    {
        cout << "destructor\t" << this << endl;
    };
    void Print()
    {
        cout <<"x = " <<x <<"\ty = " << y<<";\t"<<this<< endl;
    }
    Point& operator =(const Point& other)
    {
        x = other.x;
        y = other.y;
        cout << "operator = "<< this << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Point a(1, 2);
    Point b = a;
    a.Print();
    b.Print();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что вызывается конструктор копирования, которого у вас нет, так что он генерируется автоматически компилятором. Добавьте в свой код копирующий конструктор

```
Point(const Point& p): x(p.x), y(p.y)
{
    cout << "copy constructor\t"<< this <<endl;
}
```

и попробуйте еще раз...

P.S. не для вас, а для тех, кто может начать уточнять :) - остальные огрехи типа присваивания NULL, присваивания, а не инициализации я трогать не стал - в данном случае они несущественны.